# When to use Hash partitions in Oracle

Tags: oracle11g

In my project ,table data does not easily lend itself to range partitioning, but i would like to partition for performance and manageability reasons.
Table contains info about users for a retail domain like user id,username,email,address etc.
so can i go ahead and create hash partitions like some 4 or 6 on this table on user id column?

Please advise

Thanks,
Sreenivas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can create hash partitions on a table if there is no other natural partitioning key. It is mainly used for equally distributing the data between partititons. With the hash partitioning you can get the advantage of partition pruning and spped up the performance, however since you do not have any  control over the way the data gets distributed, hence you will not be able to use it much from the Manageability perspective.

Hope it helps

Vishad

Comment: Hi Vishad,When compared to normal table the insert /update performance is fast for hash partitioned tables right?

Comment: Inserts will be bit slower as now Oracle has to decide in which partition to keep the row. Updates should be faster if the search is on the partitioning key. But the you will need to test out the magnitude of impact